# Symfony 2 Form add options

Tags: php, symfony

1. Where I can found all possible options for add metod (FormBuilderInterface). I know there can be mapped option but what else?

---

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('task')
        ->add('dueDate', null, array('mapped' => false))
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class)
    ;
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Task',
    ));
}
```

Comment: Hi, you have asked 4 questions. Is it actually 4 different answers you are expecting? If so, can you please ask them as separate questions. This site is a Q&A site, one question, one answer type arrangement. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#built-in-field-types

This section talks about built in field types, but I suggest your read the entire page.

Comment: Yes I see now it 's inside every Built - in Field Types. So for add ( ' DueDate ', null) if the second parameter is null it's Base Fields FormType ? If yes then the first question is Answered ; )